# how to remove special characters like '(),comma' from field and display the value with separate line

Tags: string, postgresql, case

I want to separate my data that is stored into field with comma and special character. And column name is res_scheduledjobs.sq_name_new1. So my record look like:

```
            sq_name_new1
 R&M(Mahesh P. Satardekar,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble) 
 andheri 3(Santosh Navnath Mule,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble) 
 andheri 3(Santosh Navnath Mule,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)  
 ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado)
```

I want to split the record that is separated with comma into different line.
so to get this result I am executing query as:

```
select sq_name_new1,
       unnest(string_to_array(substring(sq_name_new1,'\((.*)\)'),',')) as new_column 
from res_scheduledjobs;
```

and it gives me a result like :

```
 R&M(Mahesh P. Satardekar,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)         | Ramesh Jagannath Kamble
 andheri 3(Santosh Navnath Mule,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)   | Santosh Navnath Mule
 andheri 3(Santosh Navnath Mule,Ramesh Jagannath Kamble)   | Ramesh Jagannath Kamble
 ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado) | E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam
```

but I want `' E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam'` should also be displayed with the above result as:

```
ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado) | Mangesh Govind Mogam
ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado) | Lipson Manoel Machado
```

That is, it should not take `'E) 1('` and only display the name as `'Mangesh Govind Mogam'`

Comment: Your question is quite complicated, Please elaborate or add some formatting. Then may help you.

Comment: What do you want if a column (not a record) contained the value `adheri (Arthur Dent) (Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado)` Do you always want the second pair of parentheses if there is more then one pair? Or the last pair if there are e.g. 5 of them?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  i want that,the column  (sq_name_new1) should be displayed like:

ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado) | Mangesh Govind Mogam
ANDHERI (E) 1(Mangesh Govind Mogam,Lipson Manoel Machado) | Lipson Manoel Machado

that is,it should not  display initial like 'ANDHERI (E) 1(' and the 'Lipson Manoel Machado' value will have to be displayed into new line along with its sq_name_new1.